# Why is this jquery / java script code not working in mobile / in devices?

Tags: css, javascript, child-theme, responsive

I have following script in my `header.php` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* to show back the left side bar back when the LEFT side bar is moved next/below to the center/content */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        $(window).resize(function() {
          if ($(window).width() < 1018) {            
             $('.tm_left').insertAfter(".tm_center");
             $('.tm_left').show();
          }
         else {
            $('.tm_left').insertBefore(".tm_center");
         }
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

this code change my HTML structure FROM :

```
<div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
</div
```

TO

```
<div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
</div>
```

It works fine when I resize browsers.

BUT when I check this in devices still the `.tm_left { display: none; }` also the HTML markup remains same as:

```
<div class="tm_left">
    <!-- left side bar code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_center">
    <!-- content code-->
</div>
<div class="tm_right">
    <!-- right side bar code-->
</div
```

My child theme css has this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { /*  removing side bar below the screen size 768.. starts from iPad portrait view */     
    .tm_left { display: none; width: 231px; }
}
```

Why it is not working in mobile as it works on browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not showing because the `.insertAfter()` and `.show()` functions are called on resize events only, while mobile devices do not resize. They already load the page with their mobile sized. Just make sure you also run the code on the ready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* to show back the left side bar back when the LEFT side bar is moved next/below to the center/content */
    function responsive_sidebar() {
        if ( jQuery(window).width() < 1018 ) {            
            jQuery('.tm_left').insertAfter(".tm_center");
            jQuery('.tm_left').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.tm_left').insertBefore(".tm_center");
        }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        responsive_sidebar();

        $(window).resize( responsive_sidebar ); 
    });  
</script>
```

Note that I put the code into a function, just so you have fewer lines of code/

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation with the updated code.. day saved..